# Prevent some pages to be listed

Tags: bigcommerce

I have this navigation file that contains:

```
{{!
  @param nav_items
         > either "pages" or "categories", passed from parent template
}}

<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
    {{#each nav_items}}
      <li>
        <a class="top-level-nav-link" href="{{url}}">
          {{name}}
        </a>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And I use this hook to list pages or categories:

```
{{> components/common/navigation nav_items=pages}}
```

Is there a way to implement some condition to check `if page == 'About us'` and prevent it to be listed in menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a `!==` conditional in handlebars, so I've been doing it like this.

```
  <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        {{#each nav_items}}
            {{#if name '===' 'About Us'}}
            {{else}}
              <li>
                <a class="top-level-nav-link" href="{{url}}">
                  {{name}}
                </a>
              </li>
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

There isn't an if/and conditional in handlebars, so for multiple conditions, you can nest the if/else statements.

```
  <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        {{#each nav_items}}
            {{#if name '===' 'About Us'}}
            {{else}}
              {{#if name '===' 'Contact Us'}}
              {{else}}
                <li>
                  <a class="top-level-nav-link" href="{{url}}">
                    {{name}}
                  </a>
                </li>
              {{/if}}
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: That works! But if I need more conditions like `if name '===' 'About us' AND name '===' 'Contact Us'` how this would be implemented?